# Convert a JSON buffer into .gz

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-s3, gzip

I have the following code saving a pandas data-frame to json in memory and then loading it to AWS S3:

```
json_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_json(json_buffer, orient='records', date_format='iso')
json_file_name = file_to_load.split(".")[0] + ".json"
s3_conn.put_object(Body=json_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=f"{target_path}{json_file_name}")
```

What I am trying to do is to archive the json file in gzip (.gz) format just before I put it in the S3 bucket.
Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try use `compression='gzip'` with df.to_json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following using [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html):

```
with gzip.open(json_file_name, 'wt', encoding='UTF-8') as zipfile:
    json.dump(data, zipfile)
```

This will save the `json` file in gzip format. So call is before passing to the S3 buckt.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, 'zipfile' will be the file to load now?

Comment: @TomerShalhon it will be the compressed version, but yes

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer gives simpleway but if you are using `jupyter notebook` on a `linux kernel` then you can simply do

```py
with open("temp.json", 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(json_data))

! gzip temp.json

upload("bocket_name", "name_of_the_json_file.json.gz", "temp.json.gz")
# def upload(bucket_name, item_name, file_path):

! rm temp.json.gz
```